# iOS stops sending httprequests at random[Titanium]

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, httprequest, appcelerator

I've got an app that sends geolocations every 5 seconds and if no new location is found the last found location every minute. So basically there's no way the app can stop sending the geolocation to the PHP file.

Nonetheless it does. Completely random at that. The app just stops sending to the server without an error(Because i've got an alert in my onerror) and just starts re-sending again when i open up the app to see what's going on.

It seems to work fine on Android by the way!

I've got some stuff in my info.plist to keep it alive(And it does keep it alive but just stops living at random i guess):

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>external-accessory</string>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

And my httprequest looks like this:

```
    function sendCoordinates() {
        //Reset the visual text(errors/succesmessage etc)
        if (Titanium.Network.online) {

            //Concat the GPSholder array into the toSend and than empty the GPSholder.
            //To toSend accumulates GPSholder arrays in case it can't be sent for some reason but avoids getting duplicates in the GPSholder
            //the toSend is emptied out after a succesful save.
            toSend = toSend.concat(getGPSholder());
            GPSholder = [];
            if (toSend.length > 0) {
                GPSSaved.text = '';
                minuteInterval = 0;
                var xhr=Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({enableKeepAlive: false});
                xhr.open("POST","http://xxx.nl/website/services/esrm_tracker/push_tt_positions.php");        
                xhr.onload = function(){

                    if(this.status == '200'){

                        if(this.readyState == 4){
                            var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                            switch(result.result) {
                                case 1:
                                    secondsLastSent = 0;
                                    counterBlock.text = "De laatste locatie is " + secondsLastSent + " seconden geleden verstuurd";
                                    counterBlock.show();
                                    toSend = [];
                                break;

                                case -1:
                                    GPSSaved.text = 'Authorisatie code niet geldig. Er worden geen locaties meer verstuurd.';
                                GPSstop();
                            break;

                            case -2:
                                GPSSaved.text = 'Locaties niet geldig';
                            break;

                            case -3:
                                GPSSaved.text = 'Authorisatie code niet gevonden. Er worden geen locaties meer verstuurd.';
                                GPSstop();
                            break;

                            case -10:
                                GPSstop();
                            break;

                            default:
                                GPSSaved.text = 'Onbekende fout. Er worden geen locaties meer verstuurd.';
                                GPSstop();
                            break;
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }
            xhr.onerror = function(e){ 
                GPSSaved.text = e.status + ' <- error';
                alert(e);
            };

            xhr.timeout = 10000;

            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var str = JSON.stringify(toSend);
            var params = {
                auth_key : auth_key,
                locations : str
            };

            xhr.send(params);
        }
   } else {
        GPSSaved.text = 'Geen internet. Het versturen van locaties wordt hervat als de verbinding is hervat.';
   }
}
```

Comment: as a Frisian, I'm happy to support in a question which involves the `Elfstedentocht`. Contact me if you run into more issues

Comment: Thanks for the offer. If this issue can be solved i might have something else on my sleeve to go with that haha. Nonetheless i've deleted the link for now haha

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your code you are not registering a background task for iOS. You only intend on doing it by configuring it.

I also don't think it is at random, but rather after 5 minutes after the app closes. At that point the app `pauses` until it is opened again, and thus it will continue to transmit the location.

You should have a look at this documentation: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.iOS.BackgroundService

```
var service = Ti.App.iOS.registerBackgroundService({url:'bg-service1.js'});
```

Note that it will run a different instance, and you should not include the entire app into this background service, as it will also not have a UI. Create a separate file for it, with inclusion of needed http & database calls, nothing more.

Comment: And what should i add in the backgroundservice? Just that function?

Comment: Oh, P.S. It's running on standby for about 20 minutes now without any pausing issues whatsoever. It just sends locations every minute or so(It's laying dorment on my desk).

Comment: you'll need to create a file, which has all functionality in it you will need it to work properly, since it will not know about any other files (unless you include them). This is including all dependencies

Comment: can you please define "it" in your last reply? Do i need to make a bgservice with this httprequest thingie and all things that are being used within that function?

Comment: yes. Exactly that. It will act as a standalone application. So in order for your task to work, it'll need all dependencies in the js file

Comment: Should i do this for the httprequest that sends the coordinates to the server. Or perhaps the geolocation eventlistener?

Comment: not sure in your case. However, treat it as a separate app, without UI. :)

Comment: About to start when i read this in the documentation you provided: The OS limits the total amount of time a background service can run for after the application is paused, typically to no more than 10 minutes.
The OS may terminate the background service at any point to reclaim resources. So it seems to do the exact opposite of what i want to achieve if i'm correct?

Comment: Correct, but there are exceptions, of which you are one of them: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/137252/keep-a-background-service-running

Comment: I see, i'm the one receiving regular updates... I'll tinker around

Comment: Ok, i kinda have no clue what i'm doing already. If i read the documentation i don't understand any of it really. Do i need to register the service EVERY 5 seconds? Or do i register it once at the start and just call a function within the service and get it to return my result?

Comment: Or perhaps the geolocation eventlistener? Or perhaps the counter(s) that check if something needs to be send every 5(or 60) seconds...? I'm so confused haha!